# Web2py - cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, json, web2py

Im having some troubles getting this ajax call to work. The ajax function pass a simple variable to my python controller and the controller returns the result of a query. Im working with Web2py framework. The error im getting: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects. And this is the code:

Ajax Call:

```
<script>
function TestVolumen() {
    var selectVal = $('#zonas :selected').val();    
    $.ajax({
    data: selectVal ,
    url: '/shell/default/ajax2',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'string',
    success: function(request) {
    //console.log(request[0]);
    //console.log(request[0].zona);
    selectVal = $('#zonas :selected').val();

        for (x=0;x<request.length;x++){
            if (request[x].zona == selectVal ) {
            //alert(request[x].promedio);
            //alert(request[x].zona);
            $('div#tabs .vol').html(request[x].promedio.toFixed(4));

            }
        }

        }
    });
}
</script>
```

And this is the python controller:

```
def ajax2():
import gluon.contrib.simplejson
zona = request.vars

queryvol = "select sells.product1 FROM site inner join zona on site.zone_number = zona.id inner join sells on sells.site = site.id WHERE zona.id =" + zona +" ;', as_dict = True"
vol=db.executesql(queryvol)

return gluon.contrib.simplejson.dumps(vol)
```

Thanks for the help!! I really appreciate it.

Comment: python or js is generating that error?

Comment: Python is generating an error and the variable type is None and that is why it cannot concatenate.  Please print the types of the variables before inserting it inside the sql query and you can type cast it or pass it in as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python error you see means that the value of `zona` is simply `None`. I guess this is due to a fact that you make the AJAX request incorrectly. When making a request you should define the data in `{ 'variable_name' : value }` format. For server-side: note that `request.vars` is [gluon.storage.Storage](http://www.web2py.com/examples/static/epydoc/web2py.gluon.storage.Storage-class.html) dictionary-like object.

So, to fix this - modify your AJAX request by removing `dataType: 'string',` and setting `data` to something like `{ 'zona' : selectedVal }`. Second - use `request.vars['zona']` to get the value on the server-side. Third - before writing Python code any further, read an memorize [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) by heart!

Comment: And sanity check that data coming in.

Answer (score 0):

As per PEP 249, please user bind variables.

```
queryvol = """
    INSERT INTO [TABLENAME] 
    VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %d)
    )""" % (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i)
```